# Angular 4 api call json search functionality

Tags: angular, api, http

I need to make a search functionality in an Angular 4 application, the data is already a json doc in a url external to the project folders.
I need to be able to access the data searching by title or author, and get results of the search.
I am not able to get results when I write in the input search box.

My code now:

json data*****

`[
        {
            "title": "title1",
            "author": "author1",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Isidro"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Trinidad"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "author": "author2",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Beatriz"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Rosario"
                }
            ]
        },`

app.component.html******

```
<input
    (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">

<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let result of results">
    <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
      {{ result.title }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.service.ts*********

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()

export class AppService {
  baseUrl: string = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elena-in-code/books/master/bookcollection.json';
queryUrl: string = '?search=';


  constructor(private http:Http){}

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

app.component.ts*********

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private appService: AppService){
    this.appService.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results.results;
      });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts*********

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpModule, 
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: why your baseUrl has .jsons in error image but .json in above code??

Comment: I fixed that bug in the service but still didn´t manage to get search results. so no error anymore, edited the code here. but not functionality. good eye! thx.

Comment: if its a real service that will filter the data as per `search` in the backend and give you. Since it is a `json` file you need to get the entire data and filter them in UI

Answer (score 1):

'?search='; there is no search parameter in your api thats why your code does not search .

https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries   try to replace your api with this api for test  it will work .